# How to assign the value to the Access column in the where clause?

Tags: sql, vba, excel

In My project, we connecting to MS Access from MS Excel, in excel we have one dropdown (medd) with Yes or No values. At the same time, in MS Access, we have column Med_D with Y or N values.

So, if the user selects 'Yes' from the dropdown, then it should fetch the MS Access rows where Med_D = Y.
If the user selects 'No' from the dropdown, then it should fetch the MS Access rows where Med_D in ('Y','N').

I want to check this condition in a single query, we cant use CASE in Access, tried IIF & Switch but I got failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub MakeDynamicSQL()

Const SQL As String = "select * from YourAccessTable"

Dim sWhereClause As String

```
Select Case Cells(1, 1).Text ' cell A1 contains Y or N

    Case "Y": sWhereClause = " where Med_D = 'Y'"

    Case "N": sWhereClause = " where Med_D in ('Y','N')"

    Case Else: MsgBox "error": Exit Sub

End Select

Debug.Print SQL & sWhereClause ' send this to Access
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
Select * from "Table Name" Where Med_D = "xxxxx"
```

xxxxx is the dropdown with Y and N

Im guessing your using ADODB connection?

Comment: your condition is based on the y or n in the drop down right? so thats where we put Med_D = (this is the value of your drop down)

Comment: we cant connect the two fields directly since the dropdown has Yes/No and Access column has Y/N

Answer (score 0):

here's a more detailed view of the code:
    Sub Extract()

```
Blah = yourdropdown.value

Set Con1 = New ADODB.Connection
Set RcdSet1 = New ADODB.Recordset

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

DBPath = "" <<<path of your access database
DBProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
DBParam = DBProvider & "data source =" & DBPath

Con1.Open DBParam
RcdSet1.ActiveConnection = Con1
RcdSet1.Open "Select * from "Table Name" Where Med_D = "Blah""

rcdset1.movefirst
Range("xx").copyfromrecordset rcdset1   <<< where you will paste the records to
rcdset1.close
set rcdset1 = Nothing

end sub
```

have fun =)

Comment: Cant use Where Med_D = "Blah", the value we pulling from dropdown will be like Yes/No, but in Access column, the values would be like Y/N ..